# Accessing deeper data in an array

Tags: php

**UPDATE 4:**

```
print_r( $data );
```

returns the data I posted in the original question,

but

```
print_r( $data->getAttributes() );
```

returns:

```
[namePerson/first] => Oshiro 
[contact/email] => oshiro.wanen@gmail.com 
[namePerson/last] => Wanan )
```

so it does not contain the data_identity I am after which is in `$data`

**UPDATE 3:**

It seems to have an getAttributes, so I tried:

```
$data -> data -> getAttributes('data_identity')
```

But get the error:

```
[Tue Jul 12 09:01:17 2011] [error] [client ::1] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getAttributes() on a non-object in /var/www/page1.php on line 65
```

**UPDATE 2:**

I've tried both:

```
$data -> get('data_identity')
$data -> data -> get('data_identity')
```

both give the same error:

```
[Tue Jul 12 08:46:26 2011] [error] [client ::1] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function get() on a non-object in /var/www/page1.php on line 63
```

**UPDATE 1:**

If I do this:

```
$_SESSION['returned_array'] = array("id" => $openid);
print_r( $_SESSION['returned_array'] );
```

It returns the data as I have shown above.

However, doing this:

```
$_SESSION['returned_array'] = array("id" => $openid['data:protected']['data_identity']);
print_r( $_SESSION['returned_array'] );
```

give me:

```
[Mon Jul 11 19:52:38 2011] [error] [client ::1] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use object of type LightOpenID as array in /var/www/page1.php on line 62
```

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**

Using the following:

```
print_r( $data );
```

I get:

```
[returnUrl] => http://localhost/page1.php 
[required] => Array ( ) 
[optional] => Array ( ) 
[verify_peer] => 
[capath] => 
[cainfo] => 
[identity:Lightdata:private] => 
[claimed_id:Lightdata:private] => https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?id=349fj398sdhf9h94eiwujf9843e9f398 
[server:protected] => https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud 
[version:protected] => 2 
[trustRoot:protected] => http://localhost 
[aliases:protected] => 
[identifier_select:protected] => 
[ax:protected] => 1 
[sreg:protected] => 
[data:protected] => Array ( 
    [data_ns] => http://specs.data.net/auth/2.0 
    [data_mode] => id_res 
    [data_op_endpoint] => https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud 
    [data_response_nonce] => 2011-07-05T18:04:58Z1Ctdh8tsgmlLrw 
    [data_return_to] => http://localhost/page1.php 
    [data_assoc_handle] => AOQobUflA4349fj398sdhf9h94eiwujf9843e9f3988RCX4lIqE 
    [data_signed] => op_endpoint,claimed_id,identity,return_to,response_nonce,assoc_handle,ns.ext1,ext1.mode,ext1.type.namePerson_first,ext1.value.namePerson_first,ext1.type.contact_email,ext1.value.contact_email,ext1.type.namePerson_last,ext1.value.namePerson_last 
    [data_sig] => Z8OyG9w1349fj398sdhf9h94eiwujf9843e9f3982O/a349fj398sdhf9h94eiwujf9843e9f398iw= 
    [data_identity] => https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?id=349fj398sdhf9h94eiwujf9843e9f398
    [data_claimed_id] => https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?id=349fj398sdhf9h94eiwujf9843e9f398
    [data_ns_ext1] => http://data.net/srv/ax/1.0 
    [data_ext1_mode] => fetch_response 
    [data_ext1_type_namePerson_first] => http://axschema.org/namePerson/first 
    [data_ext1_value_namePerson_first] => Oshiro 
    [data_ext1_type_contact_email] => http://axschema.org/contact/email 
    [data_ext1_value_contact_email] => oshiro.wanen@gmail.com 
    [data_ext1_type_namePerson_last] => http://axschema.org/namePerson/last 
    [data_ext1_value_namePerson_last] => Wanen
```

How do I get the following value of the array only?

```
[data_identity]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output seems to be that of an **object**, and *not* an array, and the attribute `data` is a *protected* one, thus you can't access it without an accession function.

In your object, there should be some function to get the contents of `['data']['data_identity']`.

Without a function, you can't access it's value, *unless* you are extending that class, then you can access it like `parent::data['data_identity']`.

---

#### Update

Based on the output and the class you are using, the `data` array seems to be used for the internal operations, however you can get the same value of `data_identity` via `$data->identity`

Comment: @oshirowanen: Does your class have a method called `get()`?

Comment: I'm using LightOpenID to get that data.

Comment: @oshirowanen: Which of [this classes](http://gitorious.org/lightopenid/lightopenid/trees/master)?

Answer (score 3):

```
$data['data']['data_identity'];
```

But this most likely is an object so you shouldn't do that instead you should use a method of the object that will return the required data. You should be able to use something like that:

`$data->get('data_identity');` or `$data->data->get('data_identity');`

Normally ou're not allowed to access protected method or property:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

to access it you'll need specific 'get' method.

Comment: No it's not needed this is scope of the property

Comment: `$data` is definitely an object.

Answer (score 1):

I think your $data is an object (this is why you have the visibility of the attributes).
So, try this :
`$data->getData()->data_identity`

where `getData()` is an accessor of your protected attribute `data`

Comment: This gives me the following error `[Tue Jul 12 08:52:43 2011] [error] [client ::1] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method LightOpenID::getData() in /var/www/page1.php on line 64`

Comment: This gives me an error `[Tue Jul 12 09:07:12 2011] [error] [client ::1] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/page1.php on line 66`

Comment: If the class is yours, you have to implement the getData() accessor